# LINQ VB.net Return Single Type of Object Invalid Cast

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

Ok, just needing a 2nd set of eyes looking at this to make sure the error isn't something else other than my LINQ code here.  Here's the function class itself:

```
Public Function GetJacketByPolicyID(ByVal jacketID As Int32) As tblPolicy
   Dim db As New DEVDataContext()
   Dim j As tblPolicy = db.tblPolicies.Single(Function(p) p.policyNumber = jacketID)
   Return j
End Function
```

and here is the code which calls this class function in the web control form itself:

```
Dim p As tblPolicy
Dim j As New Jackets()
p = j.GetJacketByPolicyID(3000050)
```

For some reason it's flagging the 2nd line in the GetJacketByPolicyID function saying the specified cast is not valid.  So I'm guessing it's something I'm doing wrong.  I'm sure the tblPolicy/tblPolicies class works right since I can create a new instance of a tblPolicy and set a few variables by hand and return it, so that's not it.  I've also checked the datarow I'm fetching and there's no null values in the record, so that shouldn't be it either.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would seem to get what you are looking for. Not sure why you are passing in a function for a simple query like this.

```
Public Function GetJacketByPolicyID(ByVal jacketID As Int32) As tblPolicy
 Dim _jacket as tblPolicy
 Using _db As New DEVDataContext()
  _jacket = (From _j In db.tblPolicies Where _j.policyNumber.Equals(jacketID) Select _j).Single()
 End Using
 Return _jacket
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Stingyjack....thanks for the reply.  The function is just merely an exercise in trying to figure out what to class and what not to, but I do understand and appreciate the point.

I'm still getting that Specified Cast is Not Valid error however.  I'm really puzzled and looked all through my data context definitions to see if something is strange there.  

Is there a way to simply check if the single query works without having to cast it as a tblPolicy?  In other words can I perform a LINQ query and throw it into just any ol object like Response.Write(newpolobject(0).ToString() or something?

Comment: Well... I am trying to say there is no need to pass in a function [Function(p)] for this simple statement. GetJacketByPolicyID returns a tblPolicy, just as the linq query does. I still dont get why you are trying to cast it to something different. Also its worth noting
that the VB syntax for linq is a bit different than C# and VB doesn't support (at least without heinous workarounds) some of it completely (like functions) yet.

Comment: Thanks so much StingyJack, yeah I don't like VB.net much and prefer C# any day of the week, but my client is new to .net and wanted to have a base language that they were familiar with, hence the vb.net...lol.  Anyway, I did get this to work.  I had to delete and let .net rebuild the DataContexts and it worked like a charm.  Thanks again.